# Text box gets cut off in Preview for PDF files

Tags: pdf, preview

Sometimes when I edit a text box in a PDF in Preview App the text gets cut off like this. Is there any way to fix this? It's happened in multiple files. I have Mac OS X 10.14.1.

[image]